# preventing option to inherit select css

Tags: html, css

I have added a specific color and border for a select box on hover. At the moment the options also take the same color and border when you hover on the select. Both the options and select return to their normal css state upon mouseout.  Is there a way to prevent the options from inheriting the hover css of the select box ?

My html -

```
    <div class="roi-provider-list">
        <select id="providersList" class="roi-header-select">
            <option value="">All providers</option>
            <option value="7">BELL MOBILITY</option>
            <option value="32">ROGERS WIRELESS</option>
        </select>    
    </div>
```

CSS -

```
    select.roi-header-select:hover {
    background-image: url(../../Images/Icons/arrow_down_orange.png);
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #f68c23;
    color: #f68c23;
    }
```

Ive also tried the following but to no avail -

```
    select.roi-header-select:hover > option {
    border: 1px solid #c8d1d5;
    color: #102938;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
```

Also -

```
    select.roi-header-select:hover option {
    border: 1px solid #c8d1d5;
    color: #102938;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
```

Thoughts?

Comment: what you've tried (the first try) works OK here http://jsfiddle.net/LdR29/3/

Comment: Try loading your select box on a mobile device. Then you'll understand that what you're doing might not be the best idea :p

Comment: You could try to add !important behind the properties. So instead of color: #102983; you do: color: #102983 !imporant;
I know that doesn't look nice, but it might be a way to help you out

Answer (score 1):

```
select.roi-header-select option:hover {
    your rules
}
```

Here you should overwrite all rules from select.

Comment: superrafal Sorry i should have mentioned this, i have already tried your solution. Yields no result.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a 100% width and Height like this: `height: 100%; width: 100%;` to the hover CSS